# Move an item in a List<SelectListItem> to the top

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a list in my cshtml like so

```
List<SelectListItem> country = ViewData["Country"] as List<SelectListItem>;
```

and basically I want to target the one with text "British", remove it and then insert it at the top, I have some code but I can't figure it all out.

Here is my code

```
//Move British to the top in Nationality
var british = nationality.Where(x => x.Text == "British").FirstOrDefault();
//Not sure how to remove british
nationality.Insert(0, british);
```

Comment: `nationality.Remove(british);`, but remember to make sure it's not null.

Comment: As pswg said with `Remove()` and another tip to make it simpler with `nationality.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "British")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var british = nationality.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "British"); // get item

if (british != null) // Because FirstOrDefault() will return null if item is not found in the list
{
    nationality. Remove(british); //remove it

    nationality.Insert(0, british); // insert at first
}
```

**NOTE:**

Remember `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if item is not found in the list.

Comment: *"Remember FirstOrDeafault() will throw exception if item is not found in the list."* No, it will return the default value.